How to run a test twice for authenticated and non authenticated user?
I am using spring-security for OAuth2 Authentication and Authorization, here is a similar filter chain example
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            authorize - >
            authorize
            .requestMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()))
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}

In all my tests i have been including with(oauth2Login()), example:
public class HelloControllerTests {

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnWorld() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/hello").with(oauth2Login()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, World!")));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnBob() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/hello").with(oauth2Login()).param("name", "bob"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, Bob")));
    }
}

I would like to know if it would be possible to mark the test with e.g @EnsureAuthenticatied or parametize the mockMvc such as it will run the test twice:

Once authenticated, running the expectations that i write
Once not authenticated, expecting just status 403 and a common error message


First, you probably don't want to run the same test twice (different expectations because of different pre-conditions shouldn't be part of "the same test"). However:

To repeat the exact same test, use @RepetedTest.
To change pre-conditions and keep expectations from one execution to another, use @ParameterizedTest.

By using SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.oauth2Login(), you populate the test security context with an OAuth2AuthenticationToken instance. That simulates an authorized session after a successful login from a user using authorization code flow on a Spring client (oauth2Login), and neither an anonymous request nor a REST request sent by an OAuth2 client to a resource server and authorized with a valid Bearer token.
Also, you'll never get a 403 with the code you show:

Unauthorized requests will be answered 302 (redirect to login) because of oauth2Login.
authorized requests will never get 403 forbidden because .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() says that being authenticated is enough, which is satisfied as soon as SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.oauth2Login() is used.

Fix your conf
Do not mix oauth2Login and oauth2ResourceServer
This is a common mistake, but here are a few reasons why the two are not compatible:

A resource server can (and should) be stateless (no session), when a client with oauth2Login needs sessions (to run authorization code flow and store tokens).
Protection against CSRF should be disabled only on resource servers (because it is stateless).
The security context is not populated with the same type of Authentication :

JwtAuthenticationToken by default for oauth2ResourceServer with a JWT decoder (can be changed to whatever you like by configuring the authentication converter)
BearerTokenAuthentication by default for oauth2ResourceServer access token introspection (can be changed to whatever you like by configuring a (Reactive)OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter)
OAuth2AuthenticationToken for oauth2Login (always, but with a different type of principal depending on the authorization server being OIDC or not)


The user data source for building the Authentication changes (and so does the authorities mapping):

oauth2Login uses the ID-token (if the authorization server is OIDC) or the userinfo endpoint
oauth2ResourceServer uses the access token payload (if this token is a JWT and the resource server configured with a JWT decoder) or the introspection endpoint


It is generally expected from a client with oauth2Login that it returns a 302 Redirect to login to an anonymous request to protected resources, and from resource servers that it return 401 Unauthorized.

For this reason, when an application needs to expose both oauth2Login (for instance a server-side rendered apps with Thymeleaf or OAuth2 BFFs) and REST endpoints authorized with Bearer tokens, it should expose two different Security(Web)FilterChain beans (with different @Order and the one coming first with a securityMatcher).
Fix access control
401 (unauthorized) or 302 (redirect to login) mean that request authorization failed (no authorization info at all, invalid or expired token, expired session, user didn't login yet, ...). This are status that you may get when using authenticated(). Getting one or the other depends on the filter chain configuration. Again, by default, it's 401 with oauth2ResourceServer and 302 with oauth2Login.
403 (forbidden) means that a request is successfully authorized (valid session, Bearer token, or whatever the security is based on) but is not allowed to do the required action. This status may be the result of hasAuthority(), hasRole(), and alike.
Fix Test Authentication
Once you have fixed your configuration, you should know what kind of Authentication you need in the test security context for a given request:

probably JwtAuthenticationToken in the case of a request processed by a filter chain with oauth2ResourceServer
OAuth2AuthenticationToken in the case of a user successfully authenticated with oauth2Login
AnonymousAuthenticationToken in the case of an unauthorized request (unauthorized session or missing / invalid Bearer token)

You might simulate an unauthorized request by decorating the test with:

@WithAnonymousUser
SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.anonymous()

For OAuth2AuthenticationToken and JwtAuthenticationToken, you can use:

the SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors for OAuth2: oidcLogin(), oauth2Login(), opaqueToken(), and jwt()
annotations from a lib I wrote:

@WithMockAuthentication: simulate any type of Authentication
@WithJwt: simulate a JwtAuthenticationToken by providing its JSON payload
@WithOidcLogin or @WithOAuth2Login depending on you configured the oauth2Login authorization server as an OpenID Provider or not



When the authentication converter returns something else than one of the default Authentication types or when testing access control in other components than @(Rest)Controller (it is possible to use method security on a @Service or @Repository for instance), only "my" annotations work.
"My lib" also comes with some tooling to run @ParameterizedTest with different Authentication instances in the security context. See the repo source code for samples (search for @ParameterizedTest in the source).

Hey, thank you the answer, the final code has some error handling, PKCE, CORS, and changes 302 to 403. But still has both resourceServer and oauth2Login, i have read the RFCs and pull-requests/issues from Spring Security. Our current workflow is: User clicks Login on React frontend -> Redirect to api.app.com/authorize -> redirect to provider(e.g google) -> Redirect back to frontend with JSESSIONID. I made it based on the section 6.2 of the RFC. Is this the wrong way to do it? Or it is right but i should drop the oauth2ResourceServer()? Thanks in advance

You are using just sessions (oauth2ResourceServer should be removed). Your app is stateful, which means that it won't scale easily if it needs to. You might have a look at the OAuth2 BFF pattern (with a stateful gateway in front of stateless resource servers) if you need better scalability (the gateway might still need Spring Session). Be careful, as you're using sessions and as session cookies are flagged SameSite, you'll probably need a reverse proxy (instead of CORS) to have the same origin for SPA and REST API.

Also, as explained in the answer 403 doesn't mean unauthorized, it means forbidden. You should keep conventions for statuses (use 401 for unauthorized sessions). You don't really need PKCE with a confidential OAuth2 client running on your backend. You're going to need cookie-based protection against CSRF (which is not present in the conf you show).
